# swift - updateSearchResultsForSearchController implementation

Tags: swift, search, tableview

I am trying to add searchable to my tableview, I couldn't find how to filter the search results. I am parsing JSON from an API.

```
class AuthorTableView: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var authorList: [JSON]? = [] //Data from remote API
    //search
    var searchController: UISearchController?
    var searchResultsController: UITableViewController?
    var filteredList: [JSON]? = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.searchBarObj.delegate = self
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true

    loadAuthorList()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)         
    self.hideSearchBar()
    }   

    func hideSearchBar() {
    let yOffset = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.height + UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.searchController!.searchBar.bounds.height - yOffset)
    }        

    func didDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.hideSearchBar()
    }, completion: nil)
    }
```

How should I implement search filter?

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) { 
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though some code is missing in your post..I'm adding it as per my assumption.

```
class AuthorTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate{

var searchController: UISearchController!

var authorList: [JSON]!
var searchResults: [JSON] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadAuthorList()

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "type to search"
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar // Setting searchbar in tableView header

    definesPresentationContext = true

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/////////////// FOR SEARCH /////////////////

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
    if(searchText == "")
    {
        searchResults = authorList
    }
    else
    {
        // Assuming `Author` as Class Or you may use any other method for filtering data
        searchResults = authorList.filter({ ( a: Author) -> Bool in

            let nameMatch = a.name.rangeOfString(searchText, options:
                NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
            return nameMatch != nil
        })

    }
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text
    filterContentForSearchText(searchText)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////

func loadAuthorList()
{
   //your code to get author list.
   self.authorList = [authors from API]
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchController.active
    {
        return searchResults.count ?? 0
    }
    else
    {
        return authorList?.count ?? 0
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AuthorTableViewCell // Or `UITableViewCell`
    let author = (searchController.active) ? searchResults[indexPath.row] : authorList[indexPath.row]

    cell.authorName.text = author.name

    return cell
}
}
```

Hope it will help Or atleast give some ideas for what you want achieve.

Comment: HI,I am using uitableViewController. I have a view in tableViewHeader and header has has uibutton as well searchbar. I connected searchbar to self as delegate. but still its not working.

Comment: @Pawriwes You better post you issue as a new question with some code and try to explain it with some more detail. :)